# Any way to get past Access-Control-Allow-Origin for development on my own server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting this JavaScript error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo.bar.no/API/map_tools/clean_addresses/check. Origin http://foo.bar.no:9294 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is all on the same domain and the same server, but my JavaScript project is being hosted by a standalone server script that automatically bundles the JavaScript and it's dependencies into one file.

How do I get past this restriction while I'm developing?

---

I've tried allowing my JavaScript server script to connect. This is the result of a curl to the url:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2012 09:05:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.bar.no:9294
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: text/plain

array(1) {
  ["q"]=>
  string(31) "map_tools/clean_addresses/check"
}
```

And still I get the exact same error as I pasted above. Why does Chrome still refuse to connect to the damn URL when it's obviously allowed to!?

Comment: The rules for determining an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` violation are pretty strict: any difference before the first forward slash, including the port, protocol (HTTP vs. HTTPS), and sub-domain, will thwart a traditional XHR-based AJAX request ([good article](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/) en Encosia)

Comment: Yeah I sensed that. Is there any way I can put my browser into "Development mode" or something where it will shut the %¤#@ up while I'm developing? Any Windows browser would do

Comment: You would use JSONP or a proxy to request other domain urls. The article proposes an alternative using CORS standard to bypass it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured it out. I was looking for a simple and quick fix since I only need the cross domain requests for development purposes. Turns out that I just had to set both

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.bar.no:9294");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

In my PHP script on Apache. Then in my JavaScript code:

```
# Set jQuery ajax to use 'withCredentials' globally
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

And that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Use your webserver's reverse proxy capabilities to proxy  http://foo.bar.no/API/map_tools/clean_addresses/check to http://foo.bar.no:9294/API/map_tools/clean_addresses/check.

So, as you use Apache, you should add something like

```
    <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /API/map_tools/ http://foo.bar.no:9294/API/map_tools/
    ProxyPassReverse /API/map_tools/ http://foo.bar.no:9294/API/map_tools/
```

to your vhost config

Comment: I understood nothing of that, sorry

Comment: What webserver do you use for development?

Comment: The :80 server is Apache, but the :9294 is a node script

Comment: That looks like a good long term solution, but I was really looking for something less invasive (preferably a solution I could apply just to my JavaScript client side) since this is just a short term development security bypass.

Comment: The issue I have found with this is that Apache displays "503 Service Unavailable" for a long time (up to a few minutes) every time the underlying node server is restarted. This is definitively not a good solution for development where the server may need to be restarted very often.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around cross-domain security restrictions in chrome by starting it with the `--disable-web-security` flag.

E.g. (on OS X):

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security
```

Comment: It took me a while to get this to work. The Chrome processes on Windows doesn't seem to want to die, even after I specifically refuse Chrome to run in the background. As long as the processes are running, starting the Chrome executable only opens a new window under the existing processes, so this only worked after thoroughly shutting Chrome down using the task manager. This also meant that I lost all my open tabs... The "Recently closed" menu is even gone.