# Send json with POST

Tags: jquery, json

After seek in stackoverflow i can not saw a solution.
I have this jquery code:

```
<script>

$('input#submit').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/rpc/api',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',            
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"jsonrpc": 2.0, "method": "entidades","params": {"file": "entidades.json"}}),
        success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                 },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to send the json in data parameter to a file with a bottle server which processes the json and return something.

The problem is when i execute this from chrome or another browser, i receive this in the console:

```
    OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/rpc/api 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/rpc/api. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I think the problem is because i'm executing jquery in local.
If this is the problem, how can do the same?

Comment: change http://localhost to 127.0.0.1 ??:) (That's just a guess - don't get over excited :) )

PS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586780/jquery-ajax-post-unsuccessful

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816487/any-way-to-get-past-access-control-allow-origin-for-development-on-my-own-server). Perhaps that may help you do bypass this behavior for local development purposes.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a cross domain request which is not allowed by most browsers by default. Even just different port numbers will make it a cross domain request.
You can look into CORS as a possible solution.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Another solution is to make a reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin means that you can't execute cross domain calls.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

The only way you can solve this is allowing CORS in server. 
I think there is another workaround, using JSONP instead of using $.ajax(), but I've never used it

Comment: JSONP is just for GET requests